# Android scoped storage and persistent files

Tags: android, scoped-storage

I have an app that creates a directory for backup files on the external storage and automatically creates backup files when the user exits the app. One backup file per week is created and then one backup file that is overwritten all the time with latest info.

1. The backup files can't be located in `getExternalFilesDir` since they needs to survive that the user reinstalls the app.
2. I can't use `MediaStorage` because it's not an image or video.
3. I can't use `Storage Access Framework` to ask the user every time he exits the app to save a backup file.

So how to automatically create persistent backup files with the new Scoped Storage?

(I also need to list all created backup files, if the user wants to restore one of them.)

Comment: Why not use Storage Access Framework to `CREATE_DOCUMENT` and then keep the Uri for later use?

Comment: Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user select a partition. After that you can write to the whole partion creating folders and files. Never again you have to ask the user.

Comment: `(I also need to list all created backup files, if the user wants to restore one of them.)` With ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT you can let the user select the right file.

Comment: If I use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and let the user select the folder and use persistent URI, will I have full read and write permissions to files in that folder?

Comment: .. and will the permissions be lost when clearing the data for the app?

Answer (score -2):

Backup is appropriate in the case when the user loses the device, buy new, install the app, login and get his data as they were.

Your question is looks like you try to leave on the user device something that he probably doesn't need, as far he deletes the app. If it's the general files like images, music, documents that many apps can view or edit - leave them there and do not care. If it's only your app data - they should live while your app is installed and die when the app is deleting.

**It makes sense to back up to the cloud only.** In case you don't need a personal server, here is the option: implement syncing with Dropbox or Google Drive. It's the best option just to update the app's data after each closing of the app using the service.

Comment: Many reasons could be brought about why App's data should survive its removal. Please think about a Voice recorder: I need recorded files even if I don't need the App anymore. Or about a big App that has many and many settings for its setup/initialization and I don't want to re-set all these settings at each installation (this case is the most important for Unofficial ROM users that changes Android version many often). So there isn't any fixed role about "why should the App survive its removal", but if the Developer wants to do it, it should be able to realize it.